# Pandas - Replace values based on index condition to different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, replace

If I create a dataframe like so:

```
 import pandas as pd, numpy as np
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
 replace_1=[i+random.randint(0, 50) for i in range(16)]
```

How would I change the entry in column A to be the values of replace_1 list from row 0 -15, for example? In other words, how do I replace specific cells value from a list of value based purely on index?

Comment: Are you simply asking for `df.A[:len(replace_1)] = replace_1`?

Comment: Yes but the starting position could be anything not just the 0th position. So, my final implemented code is 
                    df.A[start:start+len(replace_1)] = replace_1

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# update the column in DF with series, based on the index value
df['A'].update(replace_1)
```

result

```
    A   B
0   7   17
1   26  70
2   13  81
3   48  64
4   45  74
...     ...     ...
95  74  3
96  18  94
97  81  4
98  37  11
99  65  29
```

replace_1

```
[7, 26, 13, 48, 45, 51, 35, 53, 20, 11, 38, 16, 36, 14, 63, 24]
```

Starting DF

```
    A   B
0   75  17
1   84  70
2   57  81
3   88  64
4   78  74
...     ...     ...
95  74  3
96  18  94
97  81  4
98  37  11
99  65  29
```

Comment: The start position is not going to be always 0. so following could take care of that. 
df.A[start:start+len(replace_1)] = replace_1